# fft find low frequencies in short time history

Tags: numpy, signal-processing, fft

I have 1 time unit of signal history. My dominant frequency is 1/100 time units. When I use numpy's fft function, I am limited in resolution by the extent of the signal history. **How can I increase the resolution of my frequency comb without corrupting my signal?**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
'''
I need to caputre a low-frequency oscillation with only 1 time unit of data.
So far, I have not been able to find a way to make the fft resolution < 1.
'''
timeResolution = 10000
mytimes = np.linspace(0, 1, timeResolution)
mypressures = np.sin(2 * np.pi * mytimes / 100)


fft = np.fft.fft(mypressures[:])
T = mytimes[1] - mytimes[0]
N = mypressures.size

# fft of original signal is limitted by the maximum time
f = np.linspace(0, 1 / T, N)
filteredidx = f > 0.001
freq = f[filteredidx][np.argmax(np.abs(fft[filteredidx][:N//2]))]
print('freq bin is is ', f[1] - f[0]) # 1.0
print('frequency is ', freq) # 1.0
print('(real frequency is 0.01)')
```

I thought that I could artificially increase the time history length (and thus decrease the width of the frequency comb) by pasting the signal end-to-end and doing the fft. That didn't work for me for some reason I don't understand:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

timeResolution = 10000
mytimes = np.linspace(0, 1, timeResolution)
mypressures = np.sin(2 * np.pi * mytimes / 100)

# glue data to itself to make signal articicially longer
timesby = 1000
newtimes = np.concatenate([mytimes * ii for ii in range(1, timesby + 1)])
newpressures = np.concatenate([mypressures] * timesby)


fft = np.fft.fft(newpressures[:])
T = newtimes[1] - newtimes[0]
N = newpressures.size

# fft of original signal is limitted by the maximum time
f = np.linspace(0, 1 / T, N)
filteredidx = f > 0.001
freq = f[filteredidx][np.argmax(np.abs(fft[filteredidx][:N//2]))]
print('freq bin is is ', f[1] - f[0]) # 0.001
print('frequency is ', freq) # 1.0
print('(real frequency is 0.01)')
```

Comment: This is like saying you only know the first letter and need to know what the rest of the word is.  If you only know "b", you simply can't tell whether the word is "basketball" or "bogus" or "bat". Further data analysis on the letter "b" just won't get you there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your goal, recovering spectral information from a "too short" , i.e. << sample_rate / frequency_of_interest, window seems ambitious.

Even in the most simple case (clean sine wave, your example) the data look pretty much like a straight line (left panel below). Only after detrending we can see a tiny bit of curvature (right panel below, note the very small y-values) and that is all any hypothetical algorithm can go by. In particular, FT---as far as I can see---will not work.

[image]

If we are very lucky there is one way out: comparing derivatives.
If you have a sinosoidal signal with an offset---like `f = c + sin(om * t`´---then the 1st and 3rd derivatives will be `om * cos(om * t)` and `-om^3 * cos(om * t)`´´.
If the signal is simple and clean enough this together with robust numerical differentiation can be used to recover the frequency omega.

In the demo code below I use a SavGol filter to obtain the derivatives while getting rid of some high frequency noise (blue curve below) that had been added to the signal (orange curve). Other (better) methods of numerical differentiation may exist.

[image]

Sample run:

```
Estimated freq clean signal:   0.009998
Estimated freq noisy signal:   0.009871
```

We can see that in this very simple case the frequency is recovered ok.

It may be possible to recover multiple frequencies using more derivatives and some linear decomposition voodoo, but I'm not going to explore this here.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
'''
I need to caputre a low-frequency oscillation with only 1 time unit of data.
So far, I have not been able to find a way to make the fft resolution < 1.
'''
timeResolution = 10000
mytimes = np.linspace(0, 1, timeResolution)
mypressures = np.sin(2 * np.pi * mytimes / 100)


fft = np.fft.fft(mypressures[:])
T = mytimes[1] - mytimes[0]
N = mypressures.size

# fft of original signal is limitted by the maximum time
f = np.linspace(0, 1 / T, N)
filteredidx = f > 0.001
freq = f[filteredidx][np.argmax(np.abs(fft[filteredidx][:N//2]))]
print('freq bin is is ', f[1] - f[0]) # 1.0
print('frequency is ', freq) # 1.0
print('(real frequency is 0.01)')

import scipy.signal as ss

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(mytimes, mypressures)
plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(mytimes, ss.detrend(mypressures))
plt.figure(2)

mycorrupted = mypressures + 0.00001 * np.random.normal(size=mypressures.shape)
plt.plot(mytimes, ss.detrend(mycorrupted))
plt.plot(mytimes, ss.detrend(mypressures))

width, order = 8999, 3
hw = (width+3) // 2
dsdt = ss.savgol_filter(mypressures, width, order, 1, 1/timeResolution)[hw:-hw]
d3sdt3 = ss.savgol_filter(mypressures, width, order, 3, 1/timeResolution)[hw:-hw]
est_freq_clean = np.nanmean(np.sqrt(-d3sdt3/dsdt) / (2 * np.pi))

dsdt = ss.savgol_filter(mycorrupted, width, order, 1, 1/timeResolution)[hw:-hw]
d3sdt3 = ss.savgol_filter(mycorrupted, width, order, 3, 1/timeResolution)[hw:-hw]
est_freq_noisy = np.nanmean(np.sqrt(-d3sdt3/dsdt) / (2 * np.pi))

print(f"Estimated freq clean signal: {est_freq_clean:10.6f}")
print(f"Estimated freq noisy signal: {est_freq_noisy:10.6f}")
```

Comment: One thing that confused me about your answer if the thing about `<< sample_rate / frequency_of_interest`. I can always increase my sample rate by interpolating onto finer-spaced time intervals. If I do that to increase my sample rate, is there a simpler solution?

Comment: @kilojoules I don't think so. If you look at the first plot you can interpolate as much as you like it will always look the way it looks now. Your problem is just a very hard one I believe. Btw. sorry to be confusing. The critical thing about this inequality is that you're sampling much less than a full cycle at your frequency of interest. In your example what you have is a hundredth of a single cycle. Of course, that looks just like a straight line. Well, perhaps someone else can come up with a better idea than I. I would certainly leave the question open for some time if I were you.